# Stop GUI boot ubuntu ARM

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu, arm

I am using an ARM version of Ubuntu (Lubuntu specifically) on a [pcDuino](http://www.pcduino.com/). I want to use it as more of a server as opposed with a monitor. One of the first obvious things to do would be to disable lightdm/x starting on boot. I googled it and everyone is saying you just need to edit /etc/default/grub but grub is not used to boot the ARM version and is therefore not installed.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Which ARM image did you download for use?

Comment: The latest version [here](http://www.pcduino.com/?page_id=14) which I believe is Linaro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, run levels for Ubuntu and flavors is handled by the Upstart system.  To bypass going straight to graphical mode, you'll need to change the run level as stipulated in [the Upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#runlevels).  The Ubuntu default is graphical multi-user plus networking.

To switch to single user mode, you'll need to enter the command `sudo nano /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf` and enter the appropriate password to open the file for editing.  Once open, hit `Control-W` to search for `env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL` and change what is on the other side of the equal sign to 1.  Hit `Control-X`, and yes to the prompts, and leave nano to finish your editing.  Reboot and you should come back up in single user mode without going straight to a GUI.